# Partial Sum of a Geometric Matrix Series

Tags: matrices, geometric-series

I am looking for a formula for Partial Sum of a Geometric Matrix Series that has following structure:
$S_n = A + M^TAM+(M^T)^2AM^2+...+ (M^T)^nAM^n$. I know that for a Series of $I + A + A^2 ...$ the formula is $S_n = (I-A)^{-1}(I-A^n)$. But I struggle to generalize it to the other case. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Best regards and many thanks!

Mat

Comment: I don't know if it helps but$$M^TS_nM=S_n-A+(M^T)^{n+1}AM^{n+1}$$

Comment: Hi Peter,

many thanks for your comment. I tried to solve that equation for $S_n$, but i coudn't get it done. Any further thoughts on this?
Best regards

Comment: Another idea: Would it help if A is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: You effectively just need to invert the mapping $x\mapsto M^TxM-x$ over matrices $x$.